# Python to create zookeeper local session

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper

I wants to know if i could create a **localSession** using kazoo, i see since zookeeper 3.5.0 there's localSessions use to decrease global cluster connections, and the local session creation is at **ConnectRequest** and **CreateSession**, don't know if i missed any docs.

https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/zookeeperProgrammers.html

i tried to create a simple connection by

```
import logging
from kazoo.client import KazooClient

zk = KazooClient(hosts='127.0.0.1:2181')
zk.start()
zk.stop()
```

also i do enabled local session in zookeeper

```
localSessionsEnabled = true
localSessionsUpgradingEnabled = true
```

anything else i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i solved this myself, my configuration file were in another directory, so this configuration do works, after the start server with right setup, i could able to see local session in logs also in monitor.